# How to create a sequence column based on sequences' starts and ends

Tags: r, tidyverse, seq

I've got a two columns that contain information about sequences' starts and ends. I want to create a sequence column from that, i.e. each sequence starts when a `seq_start` is `1` and ends in first row appearing after `seq_start = 1` in which `seq_end = 1`. How can I do it with `tidyverse`? The data is shown below, where `seq` is expected output. Please note that when `seq_end = 1` and `seq_start = 1` within the same rows this produces the sequence of length one.

```
structure(list(seq_start = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
NA), seq_end = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 
1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 
1L), seq = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10L, 10L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11L, 
NA)), .Names = c("seq_start", "seq_end", "seq"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L))
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of output?

Comment: Is there a reason why `seq` value jumps from 5 to 7 (bypassing 6)? I'm not sure I understand how that works, based on the logic you described.

Comment: @Salman the sample of output is provided in `seq` column

Comment: @Z.Lin There is not, that was my mistake (I have corrected it already)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that makes heavy use of `dplyr` package's `lag()` function, along with `cumsum()` from the `base` package, to produce the expected result. It's probably not the most succinct solution out there, but I do think it's reasonably intuitive to understand:

```
d <- d %>%

  # new.seq.starts starts from 0, and increments by 1 every time seq_starts takes on 
  # the value 1, like this: 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ...
  # Rows with the same new.seq.starts value are thus part of the same "run".
  mutate(new.seq.starts = cumsum(!is.na(seq_start))) %>%

  # group by each "run"
  group_by(new.seq.starts) %>%

  # any.ending.so.far counts whether there has been ANY seq_end == 1 within the run yet.
  # first.ending is TRUE only if it's the first row (within the run) to have an ending.
  mutate(any.ending.so.far = cumsum(!is.na(seq_end)),
         first.ending = any.ending.so.far == 1 &
           (is.na(lag(any.ending.so.far)) | lag(any.ending.so.far) < 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # result keeps the new.seq.starts values only if there's no ending yet (i.e. 
  # any.ending.so.far == 0), or only just ended (first.ending == TRUE). Otherwise,
  # it takes on the value NA.
  mutate(result = ifelse(new.seq.starts > 0 &
                           (any.ending.so.far == 0 | first.ending),
                         new.seq.starts, NA)) %>%

  # Remove helper variables as they are no longer needed.
  select(-c(new.seq.starts, any.ending.so.far, first.ending))

> all.equal(d$seq, d$result)
[1] TRUE
```